# Changing the colour of Python docstring params in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, textmate

I'm looking to change the colour (or highlight) of params in Python docstrings in VS Code.

I had some look into themes, but I don't quite understand how I could add a custom scope using TextMate.

On the image below, you can see the `:param:` are the same colour as the string.
I'm looking for it to be a different / custom colour.

Might also look into highlighting the return types such as `str` or `dict`.

I'd really appreciate any and all help!

[image: Code Snippet]

Comment: The TextMate rules are quite simple to understand if you follow https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars#naming-conventions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc string is colored as a normal string.

Use the extension [Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight) to specify which text should have a different color

```
  "highlight.regexes": {
    "(:(?:param|return))( \\w+)?(:)": {
      "regexFlags": "g",
      "filterLanguageRegex": "python",
      "decorations": [
        { "color": "blue" },
        { "color": "green" },
        { "color": "blue" }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing. Yes, it is coloured as a normal string because it is one. The suggestion to use a highlighting extension is good! However it appears it will only highlight the parts of text, rather than changing font-color.

Comment: @JakubZurakowski Not in my version of VSC, see edit

Comment: Thanks @rioV8. This actually worked. I was over-complicating things haha. I hope at some point they'll add support for `:param:` (etc) in doc-strings natively to allow theme-creators to take these into consideration.

Comment: @JakubZurakowski If it is part of the Textmate rules for the language you can change the color, ask the provider of the language extension to support this

Answer (score 0):

Since this is inside the docstring there's not much you can do easily. AFAIK themes are based on the language servers definitions in the language. Docstrings are considered a whole "thing" so you can change the whole docstring colour, but not content within the docstring.

You could probably do this if you wrote a VS module, but that's a lot of work for something this minor.

Answer (score 0):

The VSCode extension "Python Sphinx Highlighter" may help. I use it for `:param` highlight.

[image]